# Firefox CSS / SVG filters don't show up

Tags: firefox, css, svg

I'm trying to determine why Firefox is not displaying any CSS filters (or SVG), for example just visit the doc below, can someone let me know if there is a setting to enable?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

[image]

[image]

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 65.0.1

Comment: @DavidPostill interesting, thanks for checking, I don't know what is going on with my instance, it won't show any filter whether it is css or svg it just shows blank in that spot. I'm using Win10x64 Pro.

Comment: Are you able to open the image? https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg

Comment: @DavidPostill yep no issues seeing that svg